# More than one text-domain is being used because of the included templates for plugins

Tags: plugins, themes, templates, multi-language

I added bbPress and WooCommerce in my theme and override some templates too. These templates contains textdomains like `bbpress` and `woocommerce`. Unfortunately I got the following error in Theme-Check:

> More than one text-domain is being used in this theme.

What is the best way to fix this? Should I change the textdomains in every template file?

Comment: yes, change the text-domain to your theme slug in the templates you included in the theme

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea because woocommerce has about 20 translations. In that case you have to translate the modified text domains, or if they don't the 50% of woocommerce will be english, but I want spanish.

Comment: OP is going to change the text-domain in the theme templates  and not the woocommerce plugin templates.

Comment: If I change the textdomain in the woocommerce/bbpress templates how will the translations work with the plugin's language files?

Comment: @user1452062 They won't, but that's the point. You can't rely on 3rd party translations within your theme. Even if the strings are exactly the same, who's to say they won't change/get removed from the 3rd party? It's now up to the theme to implement/provide the translations.

Comment: So you say the best way is to provide 20+ translations for the implemented 3rd party plugin templates?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use only your own text domain. Everything in your code should be controlled by you (or at least there should be extremely few exceptions). If your templates override the templates of other plugins, than you need to supply your own translations as you can not rely on the plugins to maintain those strings over time, and keep using them in exactly the same context.